# Ionic print to PDF the current page

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, printing

I have an Ionic app (AngularJS), and I need to print (as PDF) an app's view. Currently I'm using [`cordova-plugin-printer`](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer) but when I try to print the page, I get an error.

This is my code. Printer is available (using Android 4.4.2 and 5.1 on emulator), but always there is an error getting the page. And nothing works.

```
$scope.print = function() {
    if($cordovaPrinter.isAvailable()) {
        var page = location.href;
        $cordovaPrinter.print(page, "Document");
    } else {
        alert("Printing is not available on device");
    }
}
```

I need to print a table with rows like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in tableData">
    <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.field_one}}</td>
    <td>{{ data.field_two }}</td>
</tr>
```

And I'm afraid of my plugin doesn't support the curly brackets syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution creating a PDF (I followed [Ashteya Biharisingh's tutorial](https://gonehybrid.com/how-to-create-and-display-a-pdf-file-in-your-ionic-app/)) and wrinting it to a file using `$cordovaFile`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Document.html` instead of `Document`

```
$scope.print = function() {
if ($cordovaPrinter.isAvailable()) {
    var page = location.href;
    $cordovaPrinter.print(page, "Document.html");
} else {
    alert("Printing is not available on device");
}
```

}

Comment: Doesn't works. Anyway, I found another way to do this, creating a file instead of print it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your code.

```
var page = "//html tag as u want to print table//';
$cordovaPrinter.print(page, 'Document.html');
```

I think You forget to declare `$cordovaPrinter` in your Controller.

Comment: I solved it using `$cordovaFile`, but thanks for the answer :)